# How to transpose a matrix in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, matrix

i have a 2d matrix. how can i transpose it in objective c?

have i use nested loop to transpose it as i failed to find any method in array and mutablearray classes.

My matix is of 3x3.

```
NSMutableArray *row1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@2,@3, nil];
NSMutableArray *row2=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@4,@5,@6, nil];
NSMutableArray *row3=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@7,@8,@9, nil];

NSMutableArray *twoDArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:row1,row2,row3, nil];
NSLog(@"%@",twoDArray);
```

what to do after this?

Comment: As an aside, you can still use C style arrays in objective c, so you can define 1, 2, 3 or more dimensioned arrays. Sometimes that is easier than forcing multi dimensioned semantics into a 1d array.

Comment: There are no api for this. As Matrix or multidimentional arrays are just an implementation from developer. And it may not be fixed width always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
NSMutableArray *row1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@2,@3, nil];
NSMutableArray *row2=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@4,@5,@6, nil];
NSMutableArray *row3=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@7,@8,@9, nil];

NSMutableArray *twoDArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:row1,row2,row3, nil];
NSLog(@"%@",twoDArray);

NSMutableArray *transposedArray=[NSMutableArray new];
for (NSInteger i=0; i<[row1 count]; i++) {
    NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[row1 objectAtIndex:i],[row2 objectAtIndex:i],[row3 objectAtIndex:i],nil];
    [transposedArray addObject:array];
}
NSLog(@"Your transposed array: %@",transposedArray);
```

Comment: this answer works for the specified example, where the original matrix has 3 columns. However it's not good whenever the amount of columns in the original matrix is variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy as that:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    [result addObject:@[row1[i], row2[i], row3[i]]];
}
```

I assumed it will always be 3x3 matrix, for simplicity.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is really short and new way of using aray in c-style

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a general rectangular twoDArray. Then you can transpose it using this method.

```
-(NSArray *)transposedArray:(NSArray *)twoDArray {
    NSUInteger rows = (int) twoDArray.count;
    NSArray *a = twoDArray[0];
    NSUInteger cols = a.count;

    NSMutableArray *transposedTwoDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0; i<cols; i++)
    {
        NSMutableArray *rowArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int j=0; j<rows; j++)
        {
            [rowArr addObject:twoDArray[j][i]];
        }
        [transposedTwoDArray addObject:rowArr];
    }

    return transposedTwoDArray;
}
```